# How to remove everything after 3rd comma in Excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-entry

I have data in excel format

[image]

I want to remove all links after 3rd comma in each cell. I used this code

```
=LEFT(X13,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(X13,",","|",3)))
```

But it is not working. Can someone please help

Comment: Could you include one cell value in the body of the question for testing?

Comment: What does `But it is not working` mean, specifically?

Comment: Sir, thanks for quick response. I am very new in excel. I just want to remove all links after 3rd comma. I mean I just want to keep 3 links per cell.

Comment: Perhaps you just need to adjust the cell reference, i.e. `=LEFT(E2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(E2,",","|",3)))`

Answer (score 0):

Tested this but edited to work with cell A2:

[image]

So, no error and I separated the substitute() out to see the output of that.
cell C3 is the formula used in cell C2 and cell E5 idem for E4.

I like this as I would have used find() to find the first, then second, then third comma:

```
FIND(",",A2,FIND(",",A2,FIND(",",A2,1)+1)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula-

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",5000),3),5000))
```

If your excel support `TEXTJOIN()` then can try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()<=3]"))
```

[image]